# Can't get NUnit to work at all, regardless of version

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I am been having a separate issue, but in doing that, I created a new test project from scratch to find the issue... which hasn't helped.

- I created a new unit test project on its own, nothing else in solution.
- added NuGet for NUnit and `Should`
- created a simple unit test class:

  ```
  Imports Should
  Imports NUnit.Framework

  <TestFixture()>
  Public Class UnitTest1

      <SetUp>
      Public Sub SetUp()

      End Sub

      <Test()> Public Sub TestMethod1()
          Dim b As Boolean = False
          b.ShouldBeFalse
      End Sub

  End Class
  ```
- Tried to run the test, and it said:

  ```
  [13/03/2019 17:23:18 Warning] No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1` in C:\temp\repos\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll
  ```

This is not related to my previous post, as that was based on which version. This issue is with a new project and doesn't matter which NUnit version I use.

I have tried the following tutorials on setting up NUnit, but nothing seems to be helping.

... I feel like I have missed a step somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run non-MSTest tests from the Visual Studio Test Explorer (or context menu), you need to install the appropriate adapter.

In this case that'll be the https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.13.0, assuming you're using NUnit 3.